# CSV file to multiple sheet excel file python

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have a folder of CSV files that I need to edit. Each file has a blank line in the middle. I want to take everything under that blank line and put it into a new excel sheet while rewriting my CSV file to a xls file. How can I do this?

Comment: What did you try? Sounds like you want people to write code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+xls&oq=python+xls) revealed the [openpyxl](http://pythonhosted.org/openpyxl/) library that you can use to create XLS files.

Reading CSV is built into Python.

The rest is a simple matter of programming :) If you run into a more specific problem, please feel free to post a new question.

Comment: Thanks. I realize my question wasn't particularly specific. Ill give that a try